# How preserve decimal values in .NET Framework Soap Web Service Client

Tags: c#, .net, webservice-client

I'm consuming a SOAP web service that accepts an object as input. The object is made up of different data types , ie strings, decimals and enumerated. When i invoke the service (POST), the xml request hits the server but with TAGS only containing string data. All other tags with decimals and enumerated are missing.

The data is being lost over wire.

Note: This only happens with the .Net Framework.

Please assist.

Comment: Please make sure that the data is indeed not sent in the first place and then please provide a [mcve] of your client code.

Answer (score 1):

thank you

issue resolved, the disappearing Tags had a boolean property that needed to be set to true.
Interestingly this requirement is not important when posting with either SOAPUI or Java.

body.TESTAMT= Convert.ToDecimal(5.00);
body.TESTAMTSpecified = true;

Comment: Thanks for sharing the fix. This worked for me on a .NET 6.0 project.